Why does having a DISTINCT in an outer query increase query time by 30000x when subqueries are present?
(Using SQLite v3.35.5)
Consider this query (don't worry about the specifics -- it's just a DISTINCT select with two subqueries to get counts):
SELECT DISTINCT name,
    (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM sections s2 WHERE s1.name = s2.name) AS section_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT document_key) FROM sections s3 WHERE s1.name = s3.name) AS document_count
FROM sections s1

That query consistently takes over 30 seconds to run on a table with only 15,000 rows.
Result: 249 rows returned in 32574ms

This seems very, very slow to me. (I do have an index on the name column.)
Now -- if I remove the DISTINCT from the first line, so it opens:
SELECT name...

Now it takes 1ms to 3ms.
Result: 15729 rows returned in 1ms

Yes, removing that DISTINCT improves query speed by about 30000x, even though it results in about 60x as many rows returning.
This only happens when the subqueries are present. These two queries...
SELECT name FROM sections
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM sections

...both execute in 1-3ms.
I tested with either of the subqueries removed. Removing the first one didn't change anything, but removing the second one reduced query time to about 3 seconds. This means that the problem seems to be DISTINCT performance, both in the outer query and the (second) inner query, and especially in the combination of the two.
Why would this be? Losing the DISTINCT requires the subqueries to execute more often, so it should theoretically be slower.

I cannot explain why your query is very slow but would suggest to write SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS section_count, COUNT(DISTINCT document_key) AS document_count FROM sections GROUP BY name instead. This returns only distinct names now, but since you have the name count, no information gets lost. If you need all the rows, you could join this result with the sections.

Or rather COUNT(*) AS section_count unless you specifically have nullable name values you want to count.

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output would be useful.

Using sub queries is ideally not recommended in SQL as it has been proven to be sub optimal and cause a lot of performance problems.
The most likely cause in your case is that your sub queries get executed on every iteration when SQL tries to fetch a corresponding record of sections s1
The way I see it you have two options to optimize the performance
Using Joins (Highly Recommended)
You can use JOINS in SQL to establish relationships between your tables. This heavily simplifies your query and makes data retrieval much faster. So in your case
SELECT s1.name,
       COUNT(s2.name) AS section_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s3.document_key) AS document_count
FROM sections s1
JOIN sections s2 ON s1.name = s2.name
LEFT JOIN sections s3 ON s1.name = s3.name
GROUP BY s1.name;

Using CTE
You can use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to improve performance in some cases, especially in SQLite, by simplifying query execution and avoiding redundant calculations. CTEs can help optimize this query because they allow for reusing computed values without recalculating them for each row.
In your case this is how it could look
WITH section_counts AS (
    SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS section_count
    FROM sections
    GROUP BY name
),
document_counts AS (
    SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT document_key) AS document_count
    FROM sections
    GROUP BY name
)
SELECT sc.name, sc.section_count, dc.document_count
FROM section_counts sc
JOIN document_counts dc ON sc.name = dc.name;

Disclaimer!!
The queries posted in this answer may be wrong. The point I am trying to make here is the performance of the query in the question can be optimised by using two approaches. It can be optimized by either using JOINS or by using a CTE
Let me know if you need further help

Okay thanks for the info. So just to throw some more wood on the fire, writing queries with joins is not called eager loading. Its just called writing queries. Using joins is just plain old sql, not eager loading. As far as I can see, it's only client side (in your applications) where you have the concepts of eager loading and lazy loading - usually that's something you find in ORMs - because only in the client/application could you have the idea of delaying fetching data until you really need it. This is why your answer sounds AI-ish - it "sounds" good but is a bit off target in details.

In short DISTINCT requires additional processing to ascertain and handle the DISTINCT rows.
In your case it needs a temporary B-TREE (Index) i.e. USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT from the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN.

this albeit temporary has to be built and referenced using additional resources not necessary if not using DISTINCT (in your case if the demo correctly reflects the schema, which it may not).

As per the above EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN is your friend as is the more comprehensive EXPLAIN.
Consider the following demo (note that no indexes or primary key has been assumed and that these may have an effect on the findings):-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sections;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sections (name TEXT, document_key);
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT DISTINCT name,
    (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM sections s2 WHERE s1.name = s2.name) AS section_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT document_key) FROM sections s3 WHERE s1.name = s3.name) AS document_count
FROM sections s1
;
EXPLAIN
SELECT DISTINCT name,
    (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM sections s2 WHERE s1.name = s2.name) AS section_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT document_key) FROM sections s3 WHERE s1.name = s3.name) AS document_count
FROM sections s1
;
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT name,
    (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM sections s2 WHERE s1.name = s2.name) AS section_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT document_key) FROM sections s3 WHERE s1.name = s3.name) AS document_count
FROM sections s1
;
EXPLAIN
SELECT name,
    (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM sections s2 WHERE s1.name = s2.name) AS section_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT document_key) FROM sections s3 WHERE s1.name = s3.name) AS document_count
FROM sections s1
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sections;

This results in 4 outputs the first 2 when using DISTINCT on the first line, the the last 2 (3 and 4) without the DISTINCT on the first line. Howeve, to compare the differences the 1st and 3rd outputs are show together and then the 3rd and 4th:-



the USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT is quite obvious

The more comprehensive EXPLAIN results being (apologies for not aligning):-
0   Init    0   45  0       00  Start at 45
1   OpenEphemeral   3   0   0   k(3,B,B,B)  08  nColumn=0
2   OpenRead    0   4035    0   1   00  root=4035 iDb=0; sections
3   Rewind  0   44  0       00  
4   Column  0   0   1       00  r[1]=sections.name
5   Null    0   4   4       00  r[4..4]=NULL; Init subquery result
6   Integer 1   5   0       00  r[5]=1; LIMIT counter
7   Null    0   6   7       00  r[6..7]=NULL
8   OpenRead    1   4035    0   1   00  root=4035 iDb=0; sections
9   Rewind  1   16  0       00  
10  Column  0   0   8       00  r[8]=sections.name
11  Column  1   0   9       00  r[9]=sections.name
12  Ne  9   15  8   (BINARY)    51  if r[8]!=r[9] goto 15
13  Column  1   0   9       00  r[9]=sections.name
14  AggStep 0   9   6   count(1)    01  accum=r[6] step(r[9])
15  Next    1   10  0       01  
16  AggFinal    6   1   0   count(1)    00  accum=r[6] N=1
17  Copy    6   4   0       00  r[4]=r[6]
18  DecrJumpZero    5   19  0       00  if (--r[5])==0 goto 19
19  Copy    4   2   0       00  r[2]=r[4]
20  Null    0   10  10      00  r[10..10]=NULL; Init subquery result
21  Integer 1   11  0       00  r[11]=1; LIMIT counter
22  Null    0   12  13      00  r[12..13]=NULL
23  OpenEphemeral   4   0   0   k(1,B)  00  nColumn=0
24  OpenRead    2   4035    0   2   00  root=4035 iDb=0; sections
25  Rewind  2   35  0       00  
26  Column  0   0   9       00  r[9]=sections.name
27  Column  2   0   8       00  r[8]=sections.name
28  Ne  8   34  9   (BINARY)    51  if r[9]!=r[8] goto 34
29  Column  2   1   8       00  r[8]=sections.document_key
30  Found   4   34  8   1   00  key=r[8]
31  MakeRecord  8   1   9       00  r[9]=mkrec(r[8])
32  IdxInsert   4   9   8   1   10  key=r[9]
33  AggStep 0   8   12  count(1)    01  accum=r[12] step(r[8])
34  Next    2   26  0       01  
35  AggFinal    12  1   0   count(1)    00  accum=r[12] N=1
36  Copy    12  10  0       00  r[10]=r[12]
37  DecrJumpZero    11  38  0       00  if (--r[11])==0 goto 38
38  Copy    10  3   0       00  r[3]=r[10]
39  Found   3   43  1   3   00  key=r[1..3]
40  MakeRecord  1   3   8       00  r[8]=mkrec(r[1..3])
41  IdxInsert   3   8   1   3   10  key=r[8]
42  ResultRow   1   3   0       00  output=r[1..3]
43  Next    0   4   0       01  
44  Halt    0   0   0       00  
45  Transaction 0   0   661 0   01  usesStmtJournal=0
46  Goto    0   1   0       00  

As opposed to (without DISTINCT) :-
0   Init    0   41  0       00  Start at 41
1   OpenRead    0   4035    0   1   00  root=4035 iDb=0; sections
2   Rewind  0   40  0       00  
3   Column  0   0   1       00  r[1]=sections.name
4   Null    0   4   4       00  r[4..4]=NULL; Init subquery result
5   Integer 1   5   0       00  r[5]=1; LIMIT counter
6   Null    0   6   7       00  r[6..7]=NULL
7   OpenRead    1   4035    0   1   00  root=4035 iDb=0; sections
8   Rewind  1   15  0       00  
9   Column  0   0   8       00  r[8]=sections.name
10  Column  1   0   9       00  r[9]=sections.name
11  Ne  9   14  8   (BINARY)    51  if r[8]!=r[9] goto 14
12  Column  1   0   9       00  r[9]=sections.name
13  AggStep 0   9   6   count(1)    01  accum=r[6] step(r[9])
14  Next    1   9   0       01  
15  AggFinal    6   1   0   count(1)    00  accum=r[6] N=1
16  Copy    6   4   0       00  r[4]=r[6]
17  DecrJumpZero    5   18  0       00  if (--r[5])==0 goto 18
18  Copy    4   2   0       00  r[2]=r[4]
19  Null    0   10  10      00  r[10..10]=NULL; Init subquery result
20  Integer 1   11  0       00  r[11]=1; LIMIT counter
21  Null    0   12  13      00  r[12..13]=NULL
22  OpenEphemeral   3   0   0   k(1,B)  00  nColumn=0
23  OpenRead    2   4035    0   2   00  root=4035 iDb=0; sections
24  Rewind  2   34  0       00  
25  Column  0   0   9       00  r[9]=sections.name
26  Column  2   0   8       00  r[8]=sections.name
27  Ne  8   33  9   (BINARY)    51  if r[9]!=r[8] goto 33
28  Column  2   1   8       00  r[8]=sections.document_key
29  Found   3   33  8   1   00  key=r[8]
30  MakeRecord  8   1   9       00  r[9]=mkrec(r[8])
31  IdxInsert   3   9   8   1   10  key=r[9]
32  AggStep 0   8   12  count(1)    01  accum=r[12] step(r[8])
33  Next    2   25  0       01  
34  AggFinal    12  1   0   count(1)    00  accum=r[12] N=1
35  Copy    12  10  0       00  r[10]=r[12]
36  DecrJumpZero    11  37  0       00  if (--r[11])==0 goto 37
37  Copy    10  3   0       00  r[3]=r[10]
38  ResultRow   1   3   0       00  output=r[1..3]
39  Next    0   3   0       01  
40  Halt    0   0   0       00  
41  Transaction 0   0   661 0   01  usesStmtJournal=0
42  Goto    0   1   0       00  


The results of the EXPLAIN obviously need interpretation the following is a link about the bytecode engine https://www.sqlite.org/opcode.html
the initial clue is that with DISTINCT there are 46 lines of Bytecode as opposed to 42 when DISTINCT has been removed.

Another useful source of information (e.g. do a search on DISTINCT) is https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html which covers numerous SQLite Query Optimisation topics. Sections 10,11,15 & 17 all mention DISTINCT handling.
